# Power automate desktop detect browser tab change

Tags: browser, power-automate, webapi, browser-automation, power-automate-desktop

I want to monitor web activity using power automate desktop and do an action whenever the user changes browser tab. For the tab change detection part, I can insert some inline js to use `Page Visibility API`, but once I detect a tab change in js, how can I send this info to PAD to do an action?

Moreover, is there a better way to do it?